# Animate individual letters in a title on hover in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a title on my website and want to animate the letters when hovering over it with the mouse. Here is the relevant snippets of what I have so far:

```css
.title-text {
  color: #000000;
}
.title-text span:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title-text">
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>C</span>
</h1>
```

This works fine and individual letters turn red on hover. However, I can't seem to rotate individual letters, I tried everything from a simple `rotate: 45deg;` to an animation with KeyFrames but nothing happens. How can I animate the letters on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply transforms you need to use a `block` level element, `span`s are naturally `inline` and can't be rotated:

```css
.title-text {
  color: #000000;
}

.title-text span {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.title-text span:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title-text">
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>C</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works very well with some adjustments! The span covers other spans when rotating (on my own site) so if I rotate the first letter the second will be covered by that span and therefore it still thinks I hover the first span. This is because my spans are higher than they are wide, but that was not included in my first question so I will accept this and solve the other things somehow :)